# cpanel is showing 500 internal server error even after chaning the php version of a laravel website

Tags: php, laravel

My project is on larvel 5.8 with a node_modules folder. My problem is that my hosting server is showing 500 error internal server error event after changing the version of php in my server.

In my website built using laravel 5.8 I have used admin lte 3.0.0 as an admin panel and it is working fine in artisan server and also with localhost with php version 7.2.

But when I copy all of my code including .extension files in the public_html folder and then when I try to go to the site it shows the internal server error. 
I want at least show some error message on the screen so that I can debug the code.

Comment: Check php logs to see what the error is about

Comment: I also deleted some folder accidentally from public_HTML folder like CGI_bin. Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the laravel debugger to show error on home page

2nd thing you might be missing you dependencies or hidden files if you found all file there then just  run command on server "composer update"

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the php version you need to configure laravel cache.

Use:

php artisan config:cache

2nd all of your composer packages are based on php & laravel version.

You should try "composer update" in a testing environment with same version on the live server to see if the packages are compatible.